# Cannot override attribute in extended definition

Tags: tiles, apache-tiles, tiles-3

After upgrading from Tiles 2 to Tiles 3, it seems overriding attributes stopped working.

My `tiles.xml` has something like this where `create-form` extends from `baseLayout`. I'm getting null for the "title" attribute (but the other attributes "menu", "left", "body" are all overridden correctly). Why doesn't this work anymore for "title"? Is "title" now a reserved word?

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/layout/wireframe.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="left" value="/WEB-INF/layout/left.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/layout/body.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="create-form" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title">Create New Item</put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/forms/create-menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="left" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/forms/create-leftNavBar.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/forms/create-body.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem. I don't know why overriding an attribute in Tiles 3 only worked using the `value` attribute (not using the body of the `<put-attribute>` tag).

```
<put-attribute name="title" value="Create New Item" />
```